# can't get my code to run properly (beginner)

Tags: python

my task is to Write a script that asks the user a question with a fixed number of possible answers.  Heres what I have so far:

```
print("who's your favorite actor: Tom Cruise, Nicholas Cage, or Jonah Hill?")
user_input = input()
user_input = user_input.lower()
while user_input != "tom cruise" or "nicholas cage" or "jonah hill":
    print("No seriously, who's your favorite actor?: Tom Cruise, Nicholas Cage, or Jonah Hill")
    user_input = input()
if user_input == "tom cruise" or "nicholas cage" or "jonah hill":
    print("...Thats your favorite actor...")
```

Everytime I run I get stuck in the while loop and keep getting asked "No seriously, who's your favorite actor?: Tom Cruise, Nicholas Cage, or Jonah Hill" I used the user_input.lower() because the input has to be case INsensitve. Any help would be VERY much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use Python syntax in that way. What you can do is test for membership in the set of the three actor names:

```
while user_input not in ["tom cruise", "nicholas cage", "jonah hill"]:
```

And then, for the equality test:

```
if user_input in ["tom cruise", "nicholas cage", "jonah hill"]:
```

Comment: Please use a tuple :D

Comment: isn't ["tom cruise", "nicholas cage", "jonah hill"]: a tuple?

Comment: @TrevorScottCohen no that's a list a tuple would be: `("tom cruise", "nicholas cage", "jonah hill")`

Comment: I think a list is a better fit for this use case than a tuple, since the elements are of the same kind.

Comment: it doesn't matter in this case, the list is converted to a tuple in bytecode. see: http://pastie.org/9941173

Comment: @recursive In all cases of static lists you should use a tuple regardless of element type. Also you shouldn't consider your data structure type based off of element types, there are no types in python.

Comment: @RonE:  Python does have types.  You can read about some of the built-in ones here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html.  In fact, if you follow the link there to the tuple documentation, you'll find this: 
"Tuples are immutable sequences, typically used to store collections of heterogeneous data."  That seems to support my view, although it does go on to say that they can also be used for immutable sequences of homogeneous data.

Comment: @recursive it's important to note that by no types it does not verify types until evaluating that type. for instance `x = []; x.append(4); x.append('asdf')` will do no type checking, however `x + 4` will. The "tuples used to store heterogenous date" would more refer to lists of tuples (i.e., list of cartesian coords), which would make sense. Perhaps my original statement was worded oddly, you should not choose to use a tuple because the data is heterogenous, use it when you need an immutable set. You can, of course, ignore me and do whatever you fee is best for the situation :).